# Homepage background image sizing issue in CSS Html Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a homepage design with a background image via CSS. However when the page loads aportion of the left side and a portion of the right side remains white. I want to make it fit to screen.

Here is my **HTML** :

```
<header>
  <section class="bg">
      <div [style.color]="'white'">
        <h1>  Welcome to Shopping Cart</h1>
        <h2>  Online grocery purchase made easy.</h2>
      </div>
  </section>
</header>
```

Here is my **CSS**

```
.bg{
background-image: url('/assets/images/shopping-1.jpg');
height: 100vh;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;    
/*background-size: contain;*/
/*background-color: darkblue;*/
```

}

I have tried using `width:100vw` but its not working. The right getting more stretched and the left there is still the blank white portion. Setting `width: 84vw;` makes it correct in the right side. But the left side is still blank. I am unable to move the background image to left. How I can make the entire background image fit to the screen.

**Home-page Image**:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the margins of your parent container. Do you have margins on the header or the header's parent. The code you provided should work fine if those margins are zeroed out.
I zeroed out the body margins to give you an idea of what I mean:

```css
body {
    margin: 0
}
.bg{
    background-image: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tog3dRQxENs/maxresdefault.jpg');
    height: 100vh;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Pen:
https://codepen.io/richiegarcia/pen/QWNYrRN

Comment: Thanks Dude !  It worked. By altering the parent margin to zero, solved my issue.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your CSS:

```
.bg {
    width: 100vw !important;
}
```

Comment: Did not work ! It got stretched to the right. And in the left side there is still a white portion